# Exlude files when I backup linux tar

Tags: linux, tar, back

I'm trying to do a backup in linux I have tried this :

`tar --exclude={"logs", "volumes_docker", "Backup"} -zcvf backup1.tar.gz /home/debian`

but when I check backup1.tar.gz I find data from yje folders mentioned above.

Could you help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each directory to be excluded should ideally have its own `--exclude` flag with the full path specified. E.g.:

```
tar -zcvf backup1.tar.gz --exclude='/home/debian/logs' --exclude='/home/debian/volumes_docker' --exclude='/home/debian/Backup' /home/debian
```

Ensure that the `--exclude` path doesn't contain any symlinked directories (this has bitten me before). When tar encounters a symlinked directory specified by `--exclude`, it will exclude the symlink itself, not the target directory.

Once you have that working, for a more concise approach, you can use brace expansion in the shell (as long as your shell supports it):

```
tar -zcvf backup1.tar.gz --exclude=/home/debian/{logs,volumes_docker,Backup} /home/debian
```

Here, `--exclude=/home/debian/{logs,volumes_docker,Backup}` is expanded by the shell before the command is executed, effectively making the command equivalent to repeating the `--exclude` option for each dir.

Comment: thanks for coming back, how I Ensure that the --exclude path doesn't contain any symlinked directories ? please

Comment: No worries :) Re. symlinks, it should be obvious. What I meant was to make sure that the paths "home/debian/logs", "/home/debian/volumes_docker" and "home/debian/Backup" contain no symlinks, which it doesn't sound like they do. i.e. Is "home" a symlink? No. Is "debian" a symlink? No. Is "logs" a symlink? etc.